# Likelihood for a test data (sequence of characters) given unigram models

Tags: n-grams, language-models

I would like to find the *likelihood* of a sequence of characters (the test data), given two unigram models.

The sequence (test data) is:

```
A B C B B
```

The models are:

```
       Model 1       Model 2
P(A)     0.3           0.4  
P(B)     0.4           0.5  
P(C)     0.3           0.1
```

Basically, I would like to know the likelihood, and if I can make a prediction as to which model the sequence belong and the underlying assumptions. I understand that given any unigram language model, the likelihood (or probability) of any sequence of characters is p(sequence of characters|Model).

What I have done so far was to find the MLE for each character:

P(A) =1/5 ; P(B) = 2/5 ; P(C) = 1/5

I don't know how to compute p(sequence of characters|Model). Should I multiply these to find the likelihood and establish which model it came from? How to handle the model probabilities given?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unigram models tend to rely on the *naïve Bayes assumption*: that is, they assume that every character is independent of everything else around it.

Under this assumption, the likelihood of `A B C B B` is just the product of the individual probabilities for each letter.

This assumption, as it turns out, isn't a very good one—which is why we move up to more powerful *n*-gram models.

Comment: Thanks. But given the likelihood is p(sequence of characters|Model), how does this product of the individual probabilities determine which model would predict it?

Comment: @feijao P(seq|model) = P(first|model) P(second|model) P(third|model) etc etc. From this, and Bayes' Rule, you can get P(model|seq). Or you can just pick whichever has the highest likelihood, which is called Maximum Likelihood Estimation.